# PHP разбить строку по символу с исключением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть к примеру такая строка `123|@rand(тест {@rand(номер 1234|номер 4321)}|строка||`. Это строка параметров функции в тексте. (функция выглядит, как `{@funcname(param1|param2)}`). Каждый параметр отделяется знаком `|`

И мне нужно получить из этой строки массив с параметрами. Т.е. разбить строку по символу `|`.

Главная проблема в том, что в строке может содержаться вызов функции с такой же строкой параметров, в которой тоже содержится знак `|`. Отдельный вызов функции НЕЛЬЗЯ ДЕЛИТЬ!

Итого нужно разбить строку выше на такой массив

```js
array(
  123,
  '@rand(тест {@rand(номер 1234|номер 4321)}',
  строка,
  '', // || считать, как пустая строка
  ''
);
```

Помогите составить регулярное выражение!

Я накидал что-то такое, но это работает неправильно - `"/[^({@\w+\()]\|[^(\)})]/ui`

Comment: Почему не передать нужные параметры в виде json?

Comment: я пишу бота, который генерирует ответ по словарю json. Словарь огромный будет. В нем, чтобы каждая фраза была бы более уникальной, я использую функции - `Привет, {@rand(я Гриша|я Григорий|я Григорий, а ты дурак)}`

Comment: Я бы предложил создать файл с массивами переменных уникальных фраз. Более читабельно. А в вызове {@rand(name)}

Comment: Где name - имя переменной с массивов уникальных значений

Comment: @Николай - такая реализация есть - (@name) вместо подставляется случайное значение из списка name. Но создавать сотни таких переменных - идиотизм

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```php
preg_split('~{@\w+\(.*?\)}(?![^|])(*SKIP)(*F)|\|~u', $text)
```

- `{@` - текст `{@`
- `\w+` - одна и более букв, цифр или знак `_`
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `.*?` - ноль или более символов, отличных от символа перевода строки, как можно меньше
- `\)}` - текст `)}`
- `(?![^|])` - сразу после текущей позиции должен быть символ `|` или конец строки
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - в текущей позиции сигнализирует конец совпадения, которое отменяется, а поиск нового совпадения начинается именно с текущей позиции
- `|` - или
- `\|` - символ `|`.

Пример [кода на PHP](https://ideone.com/Y8CUYN):

```php
$text = "123|@rand(тест {@rand(номер 1234|номер 4321)}|строка||";
print_r(preg_split('~{@\w+\(.*?\)}(?![^|])(*SKIP)(*F)|\|~u', $text));
```

Результат:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => @rand(тест {@rand(номер 1234|номер 4321)}
    [2] => строка
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
)
```

Comment: Не работает для строки `123|1231|41245` или `hi|{@rand(1|2)}|bye`.

Comment: @Colorkat [**Отлично работает**](https://regex101.com/r/c86E8A/1). [PHP подтверждает](https://ideone.com/ScnLjV).

Comment: Гм, странно, в онлайн компиляторе (https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) ваше выражение разбило параметры в @rand. Онлайн тестер регулярок показывает все слеши, но только в случае, если в строке один вызов функции. Не работает для 123|34{@rand(str|str2)}24|14|||{@rand(str|str2)}

Comment: Хах, кажется заработало, спасибо. Я еще протестирую и помечу, как правильный

Comment: Блин, другая проблема появилась. Нужна регулярка, которая будет искать несколько строк с параметрами в строке типа `строка с {@rand(1|{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})})} и {@rand(1|{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})})}` Я написал такую регулярку `/{@(?<func>\w+?)\((?<params>.*)\)}/ui` Но она не так работает. В мне нужно найти строки с параметрами ВСЕХ вызовов функции. Те здесь будет 2 строки

Comment: @Colorkat Тут понадобится рекурсия, я позже посмотрю, как поправить регулярное выражение, сейчас заряд ноута заканчивается.

Comment: Окей, спасибо, можете написать мне в вк тогда) https://vk.com/color_kat

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1350217/php-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment2393920_1350217

Comment: @Colorkat Да, я уже написал ответ часа 2 назад, никак не допишу.

Comment: Блин, столкнулся с тем, что неправильно работает с такой строкой `{@rand(123|123|123), там и {@rand(13|123|123)}, бац`, Как можно исправить? P.s Проблема в бац

Comment: @Colorkat Тут неправильный формат, между `)` и `,` должна быть `}`. Ничего не получится.

Comment: А, не так написал, извините, но всё равно для строки `{@rand(тест|тест2)} 123` работает неправильно, т.е. текст после функции всё ломает

Answer (score 1):

В свете более подробного разъяснения автором задачи, я бы предложил новое решение.

```php
//Во-первых в приведенном примере автор немного ошибся и забыл у первого `@rand` в конце закрывающую скобку я ее добавил, если это не так - поправьте строку ну и регулярку
$text = "123|@rand(тест {@rand(номер 1234|номер 4321)})|строка||";

//Разбитие по `|` приведет к тому, что Вы в выходном массиве получите еще и разбитые параметры функции `@rand`. Что как Вы сами пишите и является проблемой которую Вам в том числе нужно решить
//Поэтому я бы сделал так. В строке которая содержит параметры `@rand(тест {@rand(номер 1234|номер 4321)})` вначале заменил `|` на какой-то другой символ.
if ( preg_match_all("/(@(\S+)\((.*)\))/", $text, $matches) && is_array( $matches ) && count($matches) > 0 && is_array($matches[0]) && count($matches[0]) > 0) {
    //Меняем `|` на `&`
    $rtext = preg_replace("/\|/", "&", $matches[0][0]);
    //preg_quotes экранирует спец.символы использующиеся в регулярных выражениях - а их у нас в полученной строке полно
    $text = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($matches[0][0])."/", $rtext, $text);

    //После чего спокойно разбил всю исходную строку `$text`, по символу `|`
    $params = explode("|", $text);

    if ( is_array( $params ) && count( $params ) > 0 ) {
        //Далее идем по массиву и ищем элемент-строку начинающийся на '@'
        foreach( $params as $p ) {
            $p = trim( $p );
            if ( mb_substr( $p, 0, 1) == '@' ) {
                //@rand(тест {@rand(номер 1234&номер 4321)})
                //А теперь парсим эту строку на содержание параметров
                //Если кол-во параметров другое или формат строки отличается - подправьте регулярку
                if ( preg_match_all("/^\@\S+\(\W+\{\@\S+\((.+?)\&(.+?)\)\}\)/", $p, $matches) && is_array( $matches ) && count($matches) > 0 && is_array($matches[0]) && count($matches[0]) > 0) {
                    $param1 = $matches[1][0]."\n"; //номер 1234
                    $param2 = $matches[2][0]."\n"; //номер 4321
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ахпхап, класс. Во-первых задача стоит в том, чтобы разбить строку по |. Во-вторых смысл в том, что в строке записан вызов функции - {@rand(param1|param2)}. И мне нужно получить список параметров - array(param1, param2). Я, кстати, даже регулярку в вопросе, которая описывает вызов функции привел)) короче, параметры обычно простая строка, но проблема в том, что параметром может быть другой вызов функции с символом |.

Comment: проще говоря, нужно разбить строку по символу `|`, который НЕ находится внутри конструкции вызова функции, то есть не стоит между `{@\w+\(.*` и `\)}`

Comment: Хорошая идея) Но реализация слишком большая, к тому же вы забыли, что функций может быть несколько, но это простым циклом решается. Плюс еще в таком случае нужно было бы вернуть строку в исходное положение с исходными `|`. Я буду использовать решение выше, оно лаконичнее)

Comment: @Colorkat не могу Вам этого запретить :)