# PHP регулярное выражение для поиска "функций" в строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка типа `строка с {@rand(1||{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})})} и {@rand(1|{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})})}`. Здесь `{@rand(param1|param2|)}` - вызов функции `rand` с параметрами(param1, param2 и ПУСТАЯ СТРОКА).
В качестве параметров может быть строка, пустая строка или вызов другой подобной функции.

И в этой строке мне нужно найти все вызовы функций ПЕРВОГО УРОВНЯ. Т.е. здесь результат такой

```js
<?php

array(
  '{@rand(1||{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})})}',
  '{@rand(1|{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})})}'
);
```

Я составил такую регулярку - `/{@(?<func>\w+?)\((?<params>.*)\)}/ui` (Она работает неправильно)

Но здесь проблема в том, регулярка не видит конец первой функции и захватывает всё от начала первой и конца второй функций

Помогите составить регулярное выражение)

Comment: Какого конца второй? У вас одна функция и аргументы, которые тоже являются функциями

Comment: там две функции -_- Они разделяются `и`

Comment: А вот и нет. Считайте круглые скобки. У вас сначала 3 открывающиеся, потом 3 закрывающиеся. А значит вложенные функции являются аргументами первой. Вы сами запутались в собственном синтаксисе. Может упростите его?

Comment: Нет, всё верно -_- `строка с { @rand(1||{ @rand(2|3|{ @rand(4|5 )} )} )} и { @rand(1|{ @rand(2|3|{ @rand(4|5 )} )} )}`. Упростить нет - вполне удобно писать, главное, что в самом сообщении не будет такой комбинации символов. К тому же, ужу написан большой словарь с использованием такого синтаксиса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```php
{@(?<func>\w+)(\((?<params>(?:[^()]++|(?2))*)\))}
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/gFYSBr/2). *Подробности*:

- `{@` - текст `{@`
- `(?<func>\w+)` - Подмаска "func" (кроме того, это подмаска №1): одна и более букв, цифр или знаков подчёркивания
- `(\((?<params>(?:[^()]++|(?2))*)\))` - Подмаска №2:

  - `\(` - символ `(`
  - `(?<params>(?:[^()]++|(?2))*)` - Подмаска "params": один и более символов, отличных от `(` и `)`, или рекурсивный повтор второй подмаски
  - `\)` - символ `)`
- `}` - символ `}`

См. [пример кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/XAZ3P):

```php
$re = '/{@(?<func>\w+)(\((?<params>(?:[^()]++|(?2))*)\))}/u';
$str = 'строка с {@rand(1||{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})})} и {@rand(1|{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})})}.';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, 0, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    print_r($matches["func"]);
    print_r($matches["params"]);
}
```

Результат:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => rand
    [1] => rand
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1||{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})}
    [1] => 1|{@rand(2|3|{@rand(4|5)})}
)
```

Comment: ДА, спасибо огромное, это работает прекрасно!

Comment: Можете еще подсказать, можно ли сделать, чтобы в параметрах была возможность использовать символ `)`?

Comment: @Colorkat Нельзя.

Comment: Мне кажется можно) Ведь вызов функции заканчивается всегда `)}`

Comment: @Colorkat Если у вас только фигурные скобки служат граничителями, тогда, наверное, вам вообще-то нужно `{@(?<func>\w+)\((?<params>(?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)}` ([пример работы](https://regex101.com/r/gFYSBr/4)).

Comment: Окей, уже близко) Теперь он считает последнюю скобочку частью строки, а не функции `{@rand()} Те скобка перед `}` тоже идёт в вывод

Comment: Вот я перетыкал ваше выражение - никак не могу понять, как вместо ограничителя `{}` использовать `{)}`, те чтобы круглая скобка перед фигурной не относилась к параметрам

Comment: @Colorkat Может так - https://regex101.com/r/gFYSBr/5?